# Is there a way to populate option html tag with an array in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make an option in jsx to be populated by the values in an array (currencyOptions). I used this approach but it is not working as the options still remain to be blank. The array is passed down to the component as a prop. I set the array using usestate and the data is gotten from an API. Please help.

```
import React from "react";

function Currencyrow(props) {
 const {
  currencyOptions,
  selectedCurrency,
  onChangeCurrency,
  amount,
  onChangeAmount,
} = props;

// console.log(currencyOptions);

return (
<>
  <input
    type="number"
    className="input"
    value={amount}
    onChange={onChangeAmount}
  ></input>

  <select value={selectedCurrency} onChange={onChangeCurrency}>
    {currencyOptions.map((option) => {
      <option key={option} value={option}>
        {option}
      </option>;
    })}
  </select>
  </>
 );
}

export default Currencyrow;
```

That is the component where I pass down currencyOptions as a prop from my main app.js

```
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import Currencyrow from "./Components/Currencyrow";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const BASE_URL =
   "http://api.exchangeratesapi.io/v1/latest?access_key=1fe1e64c5a8434974e17b04a023e9348";

function App() {
  const [currencyOptions, setCurrencyOptions] = useState([]);
  const [fromCurrency, setFromCurrency] = useState();
  const [toCurrency, setToCurrency] = useState();
  const [exchangeRate, setExchangeRate] = useState();
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(1);
  const [amountInFromCurrency, setAmountInFromCurrency] = useState(true);

 let toAmount, fromAmount;

  if (amountInFromCurrency) {
    fromAmount = amount;
     toAmount = fromAmount * exchangeRate;
  } else {
     toAmount = amount;
    fromAmount = amount / exchangeRate;
 }

  useEffect(() => {
   fetch(BASE_URL)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      const firstCurrency = Object.keys(data.rates)[0];
      setCurrencyOptions([Object.keys(data.rates)]);
      setFromCurrency(data.base);
       // console.log(currencyOptions);
      setToCurrency(firstCurrency);
      setExchangeRate(data.rates[firstCurrency]);
    });
 }, []);

function handleFromAmountChange() {
  // setAmount(e.target.value);
  setAmountInFromCurrency(true);
}

function handleToAmountChange() {
 // setAmount(e.target.value);
 setAmountInFromCurrency(false);
}

return (
 <>
   <h1>Convert</h1>
   <Currencyrow
     currencyOptions={currencyOptions}
     selectedCurrency={fromCurrency}
     onChangeCurrency={(e) => {
       setFromCurrency(e.target.value);
     }}
     amount={fromAmount}
     onChangeAmount={handleFromAmountChange}
   />
    <div className="equals">=</div>
    <Currencyrow
      currencyOptions={currencyOptions}
      selectedCurrency={toCurrency}
     onChangeCurrency={(e) => {
      setToCurrency(e.target.value);
     }}
     amount={toAmount}
     onChangeAmount={handleToAmountChange}
     />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I run the app the option element is still blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to populate option html tag with an array in react?

This is possible. Just as a tip, you can always try hardcoding `currencyOptions` in your `CurrencyRow` and test it out.

Looking through your code, firstly it may be not what you want wrapping [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) in an additional array in `setCurrencyOptions([Object.keys(data.rates)])`. [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) already returns an array. You probably are not accessing the actual options in your `currencyOptions.map((option) => ..)`. Try setting the keys array directly like this `setCurrencyOptions(Object.keys(data.rates))`.

Secondly, you should return the desired value inside `map` by either using it as an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) or adding the `return` keyword in front of the `option` JSX.

Other than that, is there any error displayed in the browser console? And it would certainly help you to log the mapped `option` to the console and see what you are actually getting from it.

Answer (score 0):

Your map function should return a value.

```
<select>{numbers.map((m)=>{return(<option>{m}</option>)})}</select>
```